# How to protect the page from an unauthorized user in React js using Firebase Authentication

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, jsx

I am protecting a  page using firebase authentication. If user is logged in then i am showing the page otherwise i am returning user to the login page.

There are many other pages i want to protect from unauthorized users.

I want to ask, the way i am protecting the page is it ok? should i go ahead with the same code or is there any other way that is called best practices.

**Here is the code:**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import {auth} from '../dashboard/config';
import {onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import {useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';


  const [isProtectPage, setIsProtectPage] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    
    if (user) {
      //if user is logged in show component.
      setIsProtectPage(true);

    } 
    
    else {
      //if user is not logged in hide component.
      setIsProtectPage(false);

    //And redirect user to login page.
      setTimeout(() => {
        navigate("/login")
        }, 3000);      
    }

  });
```

JSX:

```
{isProtectPage ? ( <DashboardPage /> ) 
                 : 
                 ( <h2> You are not authorized  to access this page. </h2> )
                 
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you're showing is known as **routing**: sending the visitor to the correct page for their current state. It does not offer protection, as the code you now have doesn't do anything to prevent a user from visiting any page by typing its URL int he browser.

If you want that sort of protection, you'll need to run some code on the server that also detects the visitors state and allows/prevents access to the page based on that.

But many client-side web apps don't need that, as the HTML, CSS JavaScript themselves are not secret and can be safely shared with users. Instead, such apps then protect the **data** that is shown in any of these pages, as that data is then loaded dynamically (e.g. from Firebase's Firestore or Realtime Database), and access to that data is then controlled with a server-side mechanism already (e.g. [Firebase security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)).